# updating $scope of controller A from controller B

Tags: angularjs

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('Data', function() {
    return {message: "I'm data from a service"}
})

function FirstCtrl($scope, Data){
  $scope.data = Data;
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, Data){
  //I want to send a string to the service so that the view associated with FirstCtrl is updated.
}
```

Ok, lets take this code for example.  How would one set the message string from inside SecondCtrl so that the view binded with FirstCtrl is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may share data between controllers using a service (factory), but you will not use $scope directly.

Please refer to this video for a demonstration:

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

Thumbs up for egghead \o/

Edit:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('Data', function() {
    return {message: "I'm data from a service"}
})

function FirstCtrl($scope, Data){
  $scope.data = Data;
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, Data){
   $scope.data = Data;
   // Simply set the message or bind it to an input on your view:
   $scope.data.message = 'new value' 
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/suhvtr5r/

If this doesn´t work, please share your views with us

Comment: Updated question.. Would appreciate if you could take another look as your answer is pretty close I think.

Comment: it is exactly copy and paste of the egghead link, you dont do any thing new at all!

Comment: Yeah @AliAmiri there is not much to add to the subject, the egghead link is great, I just added the fiddle to illustrate better and show it working live. Although your solution works pretty well, it adds some extra code that is not really necessary for a simple case like this.

Comment: no, it is necessary you need to have a setter, getter is not necessary for this case and I just put it in the code, but you need a setter, it is a correct way, egghead just show how to set a variable in two controller, this solution wouldn't work for a case with simplest change in the string and for that you need to have a function in your factory.

Comment: Sure I agree, it´s even better to showcase 2 different solutions and let @That1guyoverthr decide which suits better for him and learn in the process, I´m sorry if my comments sounded as a critic, it´s just lack of english practice :)

Comment: After many many hours of debugging I learned that I had to use $scope.$apply to update view because I was calling the service from within a listener object.  Thank for all your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to create another parent controller like this,and put common things to both controllers

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
<div ng-Controller="pageOneController">
    <input placeholder="{{placeholder}}" type="text" />
</div>

<div ng-Controller="pageTwoController">
    <--other html-->
</div>
</div>
app.controller('parentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.placeholder = "this is common to both child controllers";
}]);
```

Comment: This feels a little sketchy, no? I updated my question.. Any bright ideas?  Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that you need getter and setter in your service here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7863/) that do the trick for you :

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">my first cotroller : {{data.message}}</div>
    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">my second controller :
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.message" ng-change="update()">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Angular:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('Data', function () {
    return {
        message: '',
        get: function () {
            alert("DasdaS");
            return this.message;
        },
        set: function (secondCtrlStr) {
            this.message = secondCtrlStr;
        }
    };
})

function FirstCtrl($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, Data) {
    $scope.update = function () {
        Data.set($scope.data.message);
    };
}
```